# Python 2D array - list out of range (matrix)

Tags: python, arrays, list, multidimensional-array

Hi !

I am new to Python and I have written a script to perform the multiplication of matrixes.
When I test a matrix with a different number of rows and columns I get an IndexError

> IndexError: list assignment index out of range

I have found that people have already asked about this topic and I went through all the comments and replies but I still do not understand where is the issue in my script.

In my script I use the formating of the print in order to print the input at specific locations.
I have employed H and L constants to space the print of each element.

```
import os

os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')

H = 2 L = 6

A_nbColumns = 8 
A_nbLines = 8

while A_nbColumns > 7:
    A_nbColumns = int(input("Enter a column number for matrix A, max 7 ........ "))

while A_nbLines > 7:
    A_nbLines = int(input("Enter a line number for matrix A, max 7 .......... "))

os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')

A = [[0 for x in range(A_nbColumns)] for y in range(A_nbLines)]

for y in range(len(A)):
    for x in range(len(A[y])):
        print(f"\033[{(y * H + 1 )};{ x * L + 1 }H.")

for y in range(len(A)):
    for x in range(len(A[y])):
        A[x][y] = float(input(f"\033[{(y * H + 1 )};{ x * L + 1 }H"))
```

Please, may someone help me ?

Thank you in advance

Best Regards

Mathieu

Comment: `A[y][x]` instead of `A[x][y]`? I.e. switch the indices.

Comment: Thank you very much @Timus.

Comment: I do not even know how to classify the question as solved :)

Comment: In your for loops you use `y` for the first dimension and `x` for the second dimension. Therefore, when indexing you must use the same order, that is, use `A[y][x]`.

Comment: Thank you @darcamo, indeed if an array is tab[i][j], i will represent the lines, therefore the vertical axis, while j will represent the columns and the horizontal axis. I often mix up because I first think in coordinates, therefore x for the horizontal axis and y for the vertical axis. Thank you for your help.